# Having to open quantified type class evidence manually?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Does one have to manually open the evidence like in `prj'` or is there a more direct way to guide the instance solver ?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module CatLib.SO.SO_TCMatchingDict where

class OneSide a where oneSide :: a

class (OneSide a {- , ManyOtherTC a -}) => TC a
instance (OneSide a {- , ManyOtherTC a -}) => TC a

class Other f where other :: forall a. f a

instance Other f => OneSide (f x) where oneSide = other


prj :: forall f a. (forall x. TC (f x)) => f a
prj = oneSide @(f a) -- Could not deduce (Other f) arising from a use of ‘oneSide’

prj' :: forall f g tag a b. (forall x. TC (f x)) => f a
prj' = case Dict :: Dict (TC (f a)) of
  Dict -> oneSide @(f a) -- that's ok

data Dict c = c => Dict
```

Comment: Apparently, GHC 9 compiles this without errors. Are you using GHC 8 ?

Comment: Indeed. The 8.10.7 in LTS 18.25. I will try with a newer. Good to know that kind of petty stuff goes away !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
prj :: forall f a. (forall x. TC (f x)) => f a
prj = go
  where
    go :: TC (f a) => f a
    go = oneSide @(f a)
```

or, in one line:

```
prj :: forall f a. (forall x. TC (f x)) => f a
prj = oneSide :: TC (f a) => f a
```

Comment: Nice. So type annotation trumps type application, I guess